# VSCode Input UI hide

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there any possible ways to identify why an Input-UI (quickpick/inputbox) is hidden with the `onDidHide` event.

The problem is that I'm building an extension with vscode and want to do some process when the Input-UI is hidden by pressing the `Esc` key.

Comment: if the result of the Thenable is `undefined` the `Esc` key is pressed

Comment: if you don't set the option of keeping it open on losing focus, it will disappear when you switch applications (in case you want to copy some text from an other source) maybe this is a Hide reason

Comment: Yeah, I've been using `ignoreFocusOut` as true. The process i mentioned earlier is regarding a web-view triggering these Input-UI. So when this Input-UI is closed deliberately that event needs to be communicated to back to the web-view.